# Passing a range of cells into a function in vba from excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a function so that =processCells(A1:A10) will take the range of cells and allow me to add 10 to each item and display the new numbers in cells A11:A20. I want to use the function in the worksheet so the user can select the cells A1:A10 manually so therefore they could select B1:B10 etc... instead of A1:A10

My problem is passing the range of cells for a worksheet to a function and then processing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample UDF to get you started

```
Function processCells(rng As Variant, Optional AddValue = 10) As Variant
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Select Case TypeName(Application.Caller)
        Case "Range"
            ' Called from a Formula
            v = rng
            If IsArray(v) Then
                ' Called from an Array Formula
                For j = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
                For i = 1 To UBound(v, 2)
                    If IsNumeric(v(j, i)) Then
                        v(j, i) = v(j, i) + AddValue
                    End If
                Next i, j
            Else
                ' Called from a single Cell
                If IsNumeric(v) Then
                    v = v + AddValue
                End If
            End If
            processCells = v
        Case Else
            processCells = vbEmpty
    End Select
End Function
```

To use it as you describe, enter it as an Array Formula `=processCells(A1:A10)` in cells cells `A11:A20`