# Can I send the values from multiple cells to a function at once?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a project where I need to change a large quantity of cells, luckily most of them are in large clumps together in a row. Is it possible for me to select a whole range of cells and send them to a function?
An Example of my function follows

```
Function lbft3TOkgm3(A As Double) As Double
      lbft3TOkgm3 = A * 16.0184634
End Function
```

Is There any way I could select a range of cells such as

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E40:L40").Value
```

And Send these values to the function in one statement or do I need to send each cell individually?

Comment: Declare `A as Range` and you can get all the cells.  What do you want the output to be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing a range of cells into a function in vba from excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8662569/passing-a-range-of-cells-into-a-function-in-vba-from-excel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass a range: [vba pass a group of cells as range to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18168151/vba-pass-a-group-of-cells-as-range-to-function)

You can then take every cell in the range and use their value for your equation.

EDIT: You can loop through each cell in the range using a For Each, by the way.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood, this is was an easy Google, try to search before asking a question please!

Comment: Actually, not that easy at all. It seems to be too obvoius for too many people to be worth writing.